# URL Masking in .Net / HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, url-rewriting

I have a website in which I have many categories, many sub-categories within each one and many products within each of those. Since the URLs are very user-unfriendly (they contain a GUID!!!), I would like to use a method which I think is called URL Masking. For example instead of going to catalogue.aspx?ItemID=12343435323434243534, they would go to notpads.htm. This would display the same as going to catalogue.aspx?ItemID=12343435323434243534 would display, somehow.

I know I could do this by creating a file for each category / sub-category (individual products cannot be accessed individually as it is a wholesale site - customers cannot purchase directly from the site). This would be a lot of work as the server would have to update each relevant file whenever a category / sub-category / product visibility changes, or a description changes, a name changes... you get the idea...

I have tried using server-side includes but that doesn't like it when a .aspx file is specified in an html file.

I have also tried using an iframe set to 100% width / height and absolutely positioned left 0 and top 0. This works quite well, but I know there are reasons you should not use this method such as some search engines not coping with it well. I also notice that the title of the "parent" page (notepads.htm) is not the title set in the iframe (logically this is correct - but another issue I need to solve if I go ahead and use this method).

Can anyone suggest another way I could do this, or tell me whether I am going along the right lines by using iframes? Thanks.

Regards,

Richard

PS If this is the wrong name for what I am trying to do then please let me know what it actually is so I can rename / retag it.

Comment: You should look into URL-rewriting (http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/). The exact details will vary based on the web server you are using (IIS, Apache, etc..). PS - I updated your tags to include that keyword. Also, this really has nothing to do with `html` or `vb.net`.

Comment: whatever you do, DO NOT use IFrames!

Comment: Thanks. I put HTML and VB.Net because the site is made in VB.Net and I wanted to use HTML pages to display the content of .aspx pages.

Comment: @Cheeso: I used to work for a Council where it was strictly forbidden to use iFrames; that is why I put this question up. If it weren't for that job then I would've thought I'd found a solution and looked no further..

Answer (score 2):

Look into URL Rewrites. You can create a regular expression and map it to your true url. For example

```
http://mysite.com?product=banana
```

could map to

```
http://mysite.com?guid=lakjdsflkajkfj3lj3l4923892&asfd=9234983920894893
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure I have access to IIS on the server - I believe, since it is shared, that we cannot do simple (and very useful) things like this and accessing databases based on the server directly from SQL Server 2005 Management Studio... I am seriously debating upgrading to dedicated hosting...

Comment: On second thoughts that would multiply the costs by 10.... maybe not - at least not just yet anyways.

Comment: If your host uses IIS7 then the rewrite rules will be stored in web.config which you should have access to. You can ask them to enable it. If they use IIS6 then they can install the IIRF rewrite module and you can edit an iirf.txt file with all your rules. I think most hosts, even shared, would offer this feature. It is used by a lot of CMS applications.

Comment: Thanks. I should've thought of this earlier but that bit skipped my mind. I did notice that it was all in the web.config a while back when I used the module for another site. One other thing I notice, after thinking about this for a while, is that the names and values are linked in the database. I'd like notepads.htm to relate to catalogue.aspx?ItemID=1234567890. If I am not mistaken, this would require some server-side code to match the two (unless there is another way that I have not thought of). Is there a way to do this with the module? If so then it would be perfect.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. If you have catalogue.aspx?ItemID=123456890 and it maps exactly to notepads.htm then you would have a rule that maps one to one. You would create a separate rule for every page. If you had something more generic like catalogue.aspx?cat=4009320&size=849302 where cat and size map to to say "shoes" and "32cm" then you could have a rule where the user types catalogue.aspx?cat=shoes&size42cm and gets the same page. This would then be repeated for other similar pages for say other shoe sizes.

Comment: Ah ok so you're saying that every time a category / sub-category is created / name edited / remove, I should modify the rules in the web.config and restart the app? That makes sense. Would be useful if I could put that into its own config so that, if I made changes to the config file in the root directory, I could upload it without overwriting all the rules in the current live version, if you get what I mean. Not sure if I can do that - will investigate this further.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean [URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

IIS 7+ has a [rewrite module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/737/url-rewrite-module-2/) built in that you can use for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

URL Rewriters solve the problem you are describing - *When someone requests page A, display page B* - in a general way.

But yours is not a general requirement.  You seem to have a finite uuid-to-shortname mapping requirement.  This is the kind of thing you could or should set up in your app, yourself, rather than inserting a new piece of machinery into your system.

Within a default .aspx page, You'd simply do a lookup on the shortname from the url in a persistent table stored somewhere, and then call Server.Transfer() to the uuid-named page associated to that shortname.

It should be easy to prototype this.

Comment: Thanks Cheeso. I am looking into this but this would require a new page to be created every time a category / sub-category is created; use of server side code within this new page would therefore mean recompiling the application, right? Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: no, a new page for each new UUID is not what I am imagining.  Try this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx#urlrewriting_topic4